# How can I skip a line after 10 numbers have been inputed?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, if-statement

```java
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 4 != 0) {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
        sum += i;
    }
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println(sum);
```

The result I am getting is:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19,
150
```

But I want:

```
1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 
14, 15, 17, 18, 19,
150
```

I have tried using another if statement and another for-loop but I didn't arrive at my desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store how many numbers have been output in a counter variable and output a newline when that counter is divisible by 10.

```java
int sum = 0, cnt = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 4 != 0) {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
        sum += i;
        if (++cnt % 10 == 0) System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this code

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 4 != 0) {
        System.out.print(i);
        if (i % 10 != 0) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        } else {
            System.out.println();
        }
        sum += i;
    }
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question correctly you mean you want to skip a procedure and a line after 10 numbers?
If yes then use,

```
int sum = 0, count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 4 != 0) {
        if (count++ % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to tamper with the sum and print the number then use,

```
int sum = 0, count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 4 != 0) {
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
        sum += i;
        if (++count % 10 == 0)
            System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If you don't want to tamper with the sum but don't want to show the number use,

```
int sum = 0, count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 4 != 0) {
        sum += i;
        if (++count % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
    }
}
```